# UBUNTU and WIN 10 dual boot and SSD HD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I have a pc dual booting UBUNTU and Win10.
Now the system is a bit slow specially the windows.
Many people advice me to add SSD HD. Is it possible to add it but keeping the UBUNTU un touched. If yes, Then How? Please give enough details

Comment: You can clone the HDD to the SSD as long as the SSD is larger than the HDD. in Terminal: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy` where sdx is the old HDD and sdy is the new SSD. dd can be very dangerous to use and can easily overwrite a drive, Study dd a bit before proceeding. You can delete the excess partitions after cloning if you wish or use the HDD for Data.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, dual booting often ends up crashing one of your OS especially Ubuntu's grub.
How about you install both OS in different HD, for instance Ubuntu's have SSD and Windows the other HD

Comment: In fact I have now both on one HD. I would like to have each on a separate drives but I am asking how to keep the old Ubuntu installation untouched!

Comment: Cloning the HDD will leave it untouched, as long as you make no typo's. The SSD will be a duplicate of your HDD but much faster. You can remove either Windows or Ubuntu from either disk if you wish.

Comment: You have the answer form @ C.S.Cameron